# Appending FirebaseListObservable and using endAt

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm trying to 'lazy load' messages in an Angular 4 chat app, which uses Firebase as its dataset.

The idea here was to retrieve x amount of messages the first time the app loads (amount is 3 now for easy debugging) and load more messages when a user scrolls to the top or presses the 'more' button.
I've written a function for loading messages:

```
public retrieveMessages(conversationId, end?) {
  const LIMIT_TO_LAST = 3;
  if (this.firebaseUserIsAuthenticated()) {
    if (end != null) {
      console.log('retrieving next 10');
      this.messages.subscribe(messages => {
        const topMessage = messages[0].$key; 
        console.log('Top message: ' + topMessage);
        const ref = this.firebaseApp.database().ref('messages/' + conversationId);
ref.orderByChild('id').endAt(topMessage).limitToLast(LIMIT_TO_LAST).on('child_added', function (snapshot) { // This gives us the top message + 'LIMIT_TO_LAST'-1 before it
          console.log(snapshot.val());
          messages.unshift(snapshot.val());
        });
        console.log(messages);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('retrieving first 10');
      this.messages = this.db.list('messages/' + conversationId, { query: { limitToLast: LIMIT_TO_LAST } });
    }
    this.messages.subscribe(messages => {
      console.log('Retrieved messages for conversation with id ' + conversationId + '.');
    });
  }
}
```

> Question 1: I need an 'endBefore' instead of 'endAt'

The first problem here is that 'endAt' gives me the records INCLUDING the record with the 'endAt' value.:

initial message array = [message 13] [message 14] [message 15]

new message array = [message 11] [message 12] [message 13] [message 13] [message 14] [message 15]

I can ofcourse limitToLast(LIMIT_TO_LAST + 1) and remove the last object, but thats ugly. What is the correct way of doing this?
I thought of adding a timestamp key to each message (with a miliseconds value), order by this timestamp key, and then say that we want all messages for "topMessage.timestamp - 1". I've not yet tested if this would work (I don't know if the endAt key must exist) but this would give problems when there are 2 messages with the exact same timestamp, although this is unlikely, it can still happen.

Using limitToLast only is not an option here (first call: limitToLast(3), second call: limitToLast(6), and so on), since it does not mean that we only display 3 messages when we retrieved only 3.
Lets say we retrieved 3 messages, but someone writes a new message, it will also be displayed (so now we have 4 messages). If the user then presses 'loadMore' only 2 new messages would be loaded instead of 3.
This problem would be even worse when we load 3 messages, send 4 messages, and then retrieve '3 more messages'. It will then just delete the first one...

> Question 2: Appending the list of messages:

this.messages is a FirebaseListObservable<> at this moment.
As far as I know it's not possible to append this list with the newly retrieved messages.
I was thinking to create a this.messageObjects (or something) with holds an array of message-objects. Each time I retrieve more messages I could append that array.
Is this a good idea? Or is there a better way?

> Additional info

I'm using firebase ID's (-K3d--f3e2...), so I can not simply say 'endAt - 1' or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now using 2 objects instead of 1 (1 array, containing messages, 1 Subject containing that array (as value, not as reference)).

When I retrieve messages, I append these to the array and call .next() with this array (as value, not by reference) as parameter on the Subject. This does the job!